# Datetime to epoch conversion

Tags: bash, awk, epoch

I have a bash question (when using awk). I'm extracting every single instance of the first and fifth column in a textfile and piping it to a new file with the following code,

```
cut -f4 test170201.rawtxt | awk '/stream_0/ { print $1, $5  }' > testLogFile.txt
```

This is part of the file (test170201.rawtxt) I'm extracting the data from, columns `Timestamp` and `Loss`,

```
Timestamp                 Stream     Status     Seq         Loss Bytes    Delay
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577  stream_0     OK      80281          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401  stream_0     OK      80282          0  1000     38472
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560  stream_0     OK      80283          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645  stream_0     OK      80284          0  1000     38472
```

This is the result I'm getting in testLogFile.txt

```
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645 0
```

However, I want the `Timestamp` to be written in epoch in the file above. Is there an easy way of modifying the code I already have to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
Timestamp                 Stream     Status     Seq         Loss Bytes    Delay
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577  stream_0     OK      80281          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401  stream_0     OK      80282          0  1000     38472
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560  stream_0     OK      80283          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645  stream_0     OK      80284          0  1000     38472
```

You can write a POSIX Bash script to do what you are looking for:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
    then
        arr=($line)
        ts=${arr[0]}
        dec=${ts##*.}   # fractional seconds
        # GNU date may need different flags:
        epoch=$(date -j -f "%y/%m/%d.%H:%M:%S" "${ts%.*}" "+%s")
        printf "%s.%s\t%s\n" "$epoch" "$dec" "${arr[4]}"
    fi  
    done <file >out_file

$ cat out_file
1485975505.212577   0
1485975505.213401   0
1485975505.215560   0
1485975505.216645   0
```

For GNU date, try:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
    then
        arr=($line)
        ts="20${arr[0]}"
        d="${ts%%.*}"
        tmp="${ts%.*}"
        tm="${tmp#*.}"
        dec="${ts##*.}"    # fractional seconds
        epoch=$(date +"%s" --date="$d $tm" )
        printf "%s.%s\t%s\n" "$epoch" "$dec" "${arr[4]}"
    fi  
    done <file >out_file
```

For an GNU `awk` solution, you can do:

```
awk 'function epoch(s){ 
                        split(s, dt, /[/:. ]/)
                        s="20" dt[1] " " dt[2] " " dt[3] " " dt[4] " " dt[5] " " dt[6]
                        return mktime(s) "." dt[7]} 
     /^[0-9][0-9]/      { print epoch($1), $5 }'    file >out_file
```

If you don't want the fractional second included in the epoch, they are easily removed.

Comment: I tried your solution but I received the following error
Try `date --help' for more information.
date: invalid option -- 'j'. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: As stated in the comments: *GNU date may need different flags*  I only have BSD, so cannot test the GNU version. The `-j` flag tells POSIX `date` to not set the system date. I think you can just remove for [GNU date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html).

Comment: I did remove the -j flag, however received a new error, date: extra operand `+%s'

Comment: @user3325598 - removing the flag isn't the solution. You'd need to replace what [the flags in this answer](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date) *do* with whatever is equivalent in GNU date. Note that this is not a failing of this answer -- your question did not specify what platform you're running bash on, and the `date` command is not part of bash.

Comment: @dawg, I'm pretty sure that `mktime` is a GNU awk extension. It doesn't appear to be part of the `awk` in my FreeBSD or OSX machines. What `awk` variant are you using?

Comment: The platform I'm using is Debian GNU/Linux and the GNU awk version is 4.0.1.

Comment: @dawg I tried the GNU awk solution and it worked perfectly, I need the fractional second and will therefore use your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[.[:blank:]]+' '
   # use separator for dot and space (to avoid trailing time info)

   {
   # for line other than header
   if( NR>1) {
      # time is set for format "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
      #  prepare with valuable info
      T = "20"$1 " " $2
      # use correct separator
      gsub( /[\/:]/, " ", T)
      # convert to epoch
      E = mktime( T)

      # print result, adding fractionnal as mentionned later
      printf("%d.%d %s\n", E, $3, $7)
      }
     else {
        # print header (line 1)
        print $1 " "$7
        }
    }
   ' test170201.rawtxt \
   > Redirected.file
```

- self commented, code is longer for understanding purpose
- use of gnu awk for the *mktime* function not available in posix or older version

Oneliner a bit optimized here after

```
awk -F '[.[:blank:]]+' '{if(NR>1){T="20"$1" "$2;gsub(/[\/:]/," ", T);$1=mktime(T)}print $1" "$7}' test170201.rawtxt
```

Comment: But I still want to make a file of the output, could you update your solution?

Comment: added the fracitonnal + redirection as request after

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU** `awk`

**Input**

```
$ cat f
Timestamp                 Stream     Status     Seq         Loss Bytes    Delay
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577  stream_0     OK      80281          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401  stream_0     OK      80282          0  1000     38472
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560  stream_0     OK      80283          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645  stream_0     OK      80284          0  1000     38472
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{cyear = strftime("%y",systime())}
function epoch(v,       datetime){
    sub(/\./," ",v);
    split(v,datetime,/[/: ]/); 
    datetime[1] = datetime[1] <= cyear ? 2000+datetime[1] : 1900+datetime[1];
    return mktime(datetime[1] " " datetime[2] " " datetime[3] " " datetime[4]" " datetime[5]" " datetime[6])
}
/stream_0/{
    print epoch($1),$5
}' f



1485926905 0
1485926905 0
1485926905 0
1485926905 0
```

**To write to new file just redirect like below**

```
cut -f4 test170201.rawtxt | awk '
BEGIN{cyear = strftime("%y",systime());}
function epoch(v,       datetime){
    sub(/\./," ",v);
    split(v,datetime,/[/: ]/); 
    datetime[1] = datetime[1] <= cyear ? 2000+datetime[1] : 1900+datetime[1];
    return mktime(datetime[1] " " datetime[2] " " datetime[3] " " datetime[4]" " datetime[5]" " datetime[6])
}
/stream_0/{
    print epoch($1),$5
}'  > testLogFile.txt
```

Comment: Does this solution create a file containing the two columns or does it only print them?

Comment: @dawg : Corrected, problem was requester did not mention whether date format is `d-m-y` or `y-m-d` now modified index

Comment: @Ahshay Hedge 
Sorry for not being clear on the date format. I tried your solution and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: @Ahshay Hedge However, since I also need the fractional second converted into epoch, I will use the solution above instead (something I should have clarified in my question perhaps).