# Converting date to unix epoch using awk in log files

Tags: bash, awk, command-line

I have file containing multiple lines in format "[dd.mm.yyyy.] text value". I need to convert this  to "Unix epoch| text value". I tried to use awk to do this but I can't seem to find the correct command
For example, if the file is:

```
[30.08.2013 13:54:49.126] Foo
[30.08.2013 13:56:49.126] Bar
[30.08.2013 13:59:49.126] Foo bar
```

I use the following (probably too complex awk command):

`cat sample.txt | cut -c 2- |awk -F'[. :]' ' { $cmd="date --date " "\""$3$2$1" "$4":"$5":"$6"\""" +%s" ; $cmd |& getline epoch; close($cmd); printf  epoch"|"; print $0 ;}';`

The problem is that I get the time in epoch correctly but I can't access the rest of the line. The $0 (and other $ variables) contain the date command. So the output is

```
 1377863689|date --date "20130830 13:54:49" +%s
 1377863809|date --date "20130830 13:56:49" +%s
 1377863989|date --date "20130830 13:59:49" +%s
```

What I wish to get is

```
 1377863689|Foo
 1377863809|Bar
 1377863989|Foo bar
```

Is there a (preferably simple) way of accomplishing this? Should I use some other tool?

Comment: What platform and version of awk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime to epoch conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055212/datetime-to-epoch-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `gawk` (fair assumption since you are using GNU date) you can do this all internally to `gawk`:

```
$ awk  'match($0, /\[(.*)\] (.*)/, a) && 
        match(a[1], /([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4}) ([0-9:]+)(\.[0-9]+)/,b) {
          gsub(/:/," ",b[4])
          s=b[3] " " b[2] " " b[1] " " b[4]
          print mktime(s) "|" a[2]
}' file
1377896089|Foo
1377896209|Bar
1377896389|Foo bar
```

Or, a Bash solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ \[([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{4})\ +([[:digit:]:]+)\.([[:digit:]]+)\]\ +(.*) ]]
    then
        printf "%s|%s\n" $(gdate +"%s" --date="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}") "${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
    fi
done <file
```

Comment: Yes, I am using gawk. This solved my probem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to simplify it to

```
IFS=' |.|['; 
while read -r _ day month year hour _ name; do 
    date=$(date --date "$year$month$day $hour" +%s); 
    echo "$date|$name";
done < sample.txt
```

Or, if you prefer to continue with `awk`

```
awk -F'[\\[\\]. ]' '{
    split($0,a,"] ")
    ("date --date \"" $4$3$2" "$5"\" +%s") |& getline date
    printf "%s|%s\n",date,a[2]
}' sample.txt
```