# Bash: Obtain epoch time from date time string taken from file using awk

Tags: bash, date, awk, epoch

First of all, sorry as the title might not be a good one. Actually can't really think of a good title but I'll try to explain as much as I can here, so here goes,

I have a file called **timeInfo** which contains Date Time string in the following format,

```
2018-06-05 00:35:51 Controller shutdown process initiated
2018-06-05 05:32:22 Controller startup process initiated
...
...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is, I need to get this time and convert it into EPOCH and store it into a temporary file **tempFile**, what I've tried so far is ...

```
//$file points to **timeInfo** file
echo `grep 'Controller startup' $file  | date -d "`awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`" >> $TEMP_FILE`
```

On using this I get the following error,

> command substitution: line 73: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Then I tried a different approach and used the following code,

```
echo `grep "Controller startup" $file  | awk '{print $1,$2}' >> $TEMP_FILE`
```

With this I get a file **tempFile** with the following info,

> 2018-06-06 00:35:31
>
> 2018-06-06 00:51:32

Which seems to be much better but I need to have it in EPOCH! Is there a way I can change the above script to save date time string in EPOCH format inside tempFile.

Hoping to hear your suggestion! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055212/datetime-to-epoch-conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may be what you want, needs `gawk`

```
$ awk '{t=$1 FS $2; gsub(/[-:]/," ",t); print mktime(t)}' file

1528173351
1528191142
```

or perhaps this

```
$ awk '/Controller (startup|shutdown)/{t=$1 FS $2; 
                                       gsub(/[-:]/," ",t); 
                                       print mktime(t)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat logfile|awk '{print($1,$2)}' |xargs -n 1 -I_ date +'%s' --date=_
```

Cat the file. Then awk the first two fields. and the using "xargs -n 1" passing one one data at a time to the date command and the using %s to get epoch.

Comment: awk can open files just fine on it's own. Google UUOC.